# Failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount494302715/Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am pretty new to Docker and have no idea how to solve following problem:

1. My command : docker-compose -f .\docker-compose.yml -f .\docker-compose.override.yml up -d
2. Error: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount494302715/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
3. Structure of the project: [image]

Comment: The error message says that there's not a Dockerfile in some directory you name in a `build:` or `build: { context: }` directory.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including enough of the `docker-compose.yml` file to demonstrate the problem directly in the question as text?  Which directory has the Dockerfile you're trying to build?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Dockerfile in the directory or you have selected the wrong git branch.

Answer (score 0):

Show us how you build your docker-compose file. Probably you are referring to a Dockerfile which does not exist.